# Order an array of objects by the value of their enums in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sorting

I have an array of CLBeacon objects which all have a property .proximity.

I want to order the array by this property which contains the CLProximity enum. So I want all objects to be in order IMMEDIATE, NEAR, FAR, UNKNOWN.

Is there a way to do this neatly without resorting to a bunch of if statements?

Comment: I thought of ordering by rawValue but in this case that doesn't even work because Unknown is first in the enum (and I want that to be ordered last).

Comment: easiest thing I can think of right now would be to create a collection to assign them int values that you can compare

Comment: What would be code to do that quickly? Zip them with a number?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you define a (computed read-only) property `sortIndex` of `CLProximity`

```
extension CLProximity {
    var sortIndex : Int {
        switch self {
        case .Immediate:
            return 0
        case .Near:
            return 1
        case .Far:
            return 2
        case .Unknown:
            return 3
        }
    }
}
```

then you can sort an array of beacons with

```
let sortedBeacons = sorted(beacons) { $0.proximity.sortIndex < $1.proximity.sortIndex }
```

If `.Unknown` is the only `CLProximity` value that needs
"special treatment" and all other possible values are in the desired
relative order then you can simplify the property definition to

```
extension CLProximity {
    var sortIndex : Int {
        return self == .Unknown ? Int.max : rawValue
    }
}
```

Comment: This is neat and it would have had my preference to attach the correct data to CLProximity though I wasn't sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom comparator and sort an array using that ,

You will "say" for all objects that has "unknown" proximity are "bigger" than others

```
var sortedArray = persons.sortedArrayUsingComparator {
    (obj1, obj2) -> NSComparisonResult in


    if obj1.proximity.rawValue == obj12.proximity.rawValue {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
    } else if obj1.proximity == .UNKNOWN || obj1.proximity.rawValue > obj12.proximity.rawValue {
        return NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    }
    return NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Julia wrote above I had cobbled this together:

```
    self.beacons = beacons as! [CLBeacon]

    var tempBeacons = zip(self.beacons, self.beacons.map({
        (b: CLBeacon) -> Int in
        if b.proximity == .Immediate {
            return 0
        } else if b.proximity == .Near {
            return 1
        } else if b.proximity == .Far {
            return 2
        } else if b.proximity == .Unknown {
            return 3
        }
        return 0
    }))

    self.beacons = sorted(tempBeacons, {$0.1 < $1.1}).map({ $0.0 })
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Martin answer.
You can also create Int enum and assign value to it and then sort it like below.

```
enum myEnum: Int {
    case A = 0
    case B = 1
    case C = 2
    case D = 3
}
let myData : [myEnum:[String]] = [.C:["3"],.D:["4"],.B:["2"],.A:["1"]]
print(myData.first?.key)

let newData = myData.sorted(by: { $0.key.rawValue < $1.key.rawValue })
print(newData.first?.key)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

Now you can just add Comparable to your enum and it respects the order

```
enum ContainerLevel: Comparable {
case empty
case almostEmpty
case halfFull
case almostFull
case full
```

}

```
//Are we running low?

let needMoreCoffee = coffeeMugLevel > .halfFull
```

print(needMoreCoffee)   //true

[Link to more Code examples](https://emptytheory.com/2020/06/30/using-comparable-with-enumerations-in-swift-5-3/)